# inotify IN_CLOSE_WRITE only detecting files if copied to directory

Tags: c, file, inotify

The code I've got works fine when a file is copied (ctrl+C, ctrl+V) into the scanned directory, however if it is dragged/dropped or moved using the terminal (`mv`) the file is not detected. I wondered if this was a known issue, and if `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` is not the correct method to use. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `mv` is a *directory*-operation. It doesn't affect the file. (so, instead/also you should *listen* to directory-events)

Answer (score 0):

Using `IN_MOVED_TO` instead of `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` is the solution to this problem.